# я считал текст из файл и поместил его в buffer,как мне его вывести по буквам(мне нужно вывести только русские буквы)?

Tags: ассемблер, masm32

```
invoke  open_file,\                 ; Открываем входной файл
        input_name_addr,\
        1

mov     input_file, eax
cmp     eax, 0                      ; Если файл неудалось открыть, 
je      exit                        ;   то завершаем программу


invoke  open_file,\                 ; Открываем выходной файл
        output_name_addr,\
        0
mov     output_file, eax
cmp     eax, 0                      ; Если файл неудалось открыть, 
je      exit                        ;   то завершаем программу

invoke  ReadFile,\          ; Считываем файл в буфер
        input_file,\
        ADDR buffer,\
        buffer_size,\
        ADDR count_read,\
        NULL
```

mov edi,0
 invoke MessageBox, 0, addr buffer[edi] , addr fmt, MB_OK; здесь я пытаюсь вывести слово но мне его надо вывести по буквам

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xor     esi, esi            ;Индекс в буфере ввода
xor     edi, edi 
mov al, buffer[esi]
mov mas[0],al
invoke MessageBox, 0, addr mas[0], addr request_name , MB_OK
```